# Number of double cosets $H\backslash G/K$ where $G=S_{10}$ and $H=K=S_9$ is a subgroup permuting the integers $\{1,2,...,9\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**Past year paper question**

Suppose $\pi$ is the group action of $G$ on a set $X$.
Fix $x_0 \in X$ and let $K$ be the stabilizer of $x_0$ in $G$.
We assume that $X=Gx_0$ is a single orbit of $G$.
Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$.

For $x\in X$, let $O(x)=Hx$ denote the $H$-orbit of $x \in X$.
Let $\mathcal{O}_H$ be the set of $H$-orbits on $X$.

(i) Show that $f: H\backslash G/K \to \mathcal{O}_H$ given by $f(HgK)=O(gx_0)$ is a well-defined map, and a bijection. (I have done this part).

(ii) Compute the number of double cosets $H\backslash G/K$ where $G=S_{10}$ and $H=K=S_9$ is a subgroup permuting the integers $\{1,2,...,9\}$.

**Attempt**

I am quite confused as to what the answer is. If we let $X=\{1,2,...,10\}$ and $x_0=10$, then we have that $X$ is a single $G$-orbit. And we have $K$ stabilizes $x_0$. Then the $H$-orbit of $1$ is $\{1,2,...,9\}$. And if we pick say $g=(1\;10) \in G$, then the orbit of $Hg$ of $1$ is $10$. So there are $2$ $H$-orbits and hence $2$ double cosets...?

Can I check if my reasoning is correct?

Comment: Yes, except that I don't know why you consider orbits of $g1$ instead of directly of elements of $X$. -- Following (i) , you are supposed to count $\mathcal O_H$, and the two orbits are $\{10\}$ and $\{1,\ldots,9\}$

Comment: Yes I think that was a mistake, I should have counted the distinct orbits of $10$ cause thats the $x_0$ I chose